# Converting numeric value to character,

Tags: sas

Hi i have a column Age which is numeric i want to convert all its values to character

I am trying the code below. This code gives me error:

> ERROR 85-322: Expecting a format name

```
DATA Diary2;
SET Diary;
FORMAT AGE2 = PUT(AGE, $6.);
RUN;
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are making this transformation ?  Formats can be used to affect how a value is displayed in output or viewing and do not necessarily require a type conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the correct syntax for the assignment statement to create the new variable AGE2.

```
AGE2 = PUT(AGE, 6.);
```